# how to navigate user to correct page?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$pages = array('Text1.php', 'Text2.php', 'Text3.php', 'Text4.php', 'Text5.php');

// Track $latest in either a session variable
// $current will be dependent upon the page you're on

$latest = $_SESSION['latest'];
$current = basename(__FILE__); 

$currentPages = array_search($current, $pages);
$latestPages = array_search($latest, $pages);

if ($currentPages - $latestPages > 1 ) {
    ?>
<div class="boxed">
  <a href="">Continue</a>
<br/>
<a href="Text1.php" id="createLink">Create New</a>
</div>

<?



} else {
    // let user do their step
}

?>
```

I have an array which contains five pages. Now this page `steps.php` is externalized and stored in an an `include()` which is stored in 5 php pages, the same php pages stored in the array above in the array.

Now what I am trying to do is the user is suppose to follow the page structure. So if the user is on one of the pages in the array, they cannot access another page until they have submitted the page they are currently on.

But my question is that if the user click on the `Continue` link, how can I get the link `</a>` to link to the correct page so it navigates the user to the page they should be correctly on.

Comment: Do you mean you wan to redirect to another page with php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how you can direct the user to the correct 'next' page when they click on `Continue`, you can output the next page using the currentPages index + 1

```
<? if ($currentPages - $latestPages > 1 ) { ?>
<div class="boxed">
  <a href="<?= $pages[$currentPages+1] ?>">Continue</a>
<br/>
<a href="Text1.php" id="createLink">Create New</a>
</div>

<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, you are trying to implement something like pagination? You should put current, previous, and next pages in the `SESSION` variable, so in every request you can check whether the  user is in the `SESSION['current']` page, and tries to go to the `SESSION['previous']` or the `SESSION['next']` page, also you should send a 'hiddenfield' value to the server in order to check if the user 'submitted' the page(but of course, one can simply read your html and find the 'hidden' field). Or you can simply check whether the submit button's 'name' is in the POST(or GET)? (`if($_POST['NAME_OF_SUBMIT']){}`) - but again it is simple to falsify, too.